# fwrite() return value does not match with file size

Tags: c, fwrite

I am using `fwrite()` to write data to the file in a loop. It repeats for 40 times, but during the first `fwrite()` last few KBs are not written to the file. Whereas the consecutive `fwrite()` works fine.When I run for a single chunk say,4000 bytes `fwrite()` returns 4000, but the file content is less than 4000 (nearly 3000 bytes). There is no error reported during `perror()` also. Kindly help me in this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** compilable example of your code.

Comment: Making a wild, wild guess about the code I imagine you may have written, is this binary data? And are you writing it to a file opened as binary (e.g. `fopen("filename", "wb");`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fwrite` doesn't write to a file. The function writes to a buffered file stream. The buffer is flushed to disk when you close the file with `fclose` or flush the buffer with `fflush`. Use the appropriate function to empty the buffer.

The buffer is used to get a good performance. If performance is not your concern and you need the direct write to disk you can use the `setbuf` or `setvbuf` function to disable the buffer. (Thanks for comment by Barmar).

Comment: You can also disable buffering by using `setbuf()`.